# How to create a 30 min count down timer in php

Tags: php, timer, countdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Countdown timer built on PHP and jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115620/countdown-timer-built-on-php-and-jquery)

I need create a 30 min count down timer and to display message box after 30 min over

Comment: This is probably better implemented on the client-side via JavaScript.

Comment: Think you are searching for an ajax solution (jquery / javascript +php file)

Comment: Have you attempted _anything_ yourself, or are you looking for a complete solution? You need to at least try doing this yourself.

Comment: What you are looking for is an AJAX countdownlike mentioned here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115620/countdown-timer-built-on-php-and-jquery

Comment: Try out https://github.com/vkiryukhin/Smartupdater =) Should be very easy

Comment: let us know when you found asolution and if we could help you, also accept then an answer if it helped solving the problem

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it directly in PHP as PHP is run on the server.

You could pop out some javascript that runs a countdown timer - you can google for a bucket of tutorials on that.

You could however possibly insert a row into a database with the start time and check it on a regular basis as scripts run - then display it one the next page that is loaded after the time has expired.

Edit: As Daniel correctly points out in the comment below (+1 btw) you could have a PHP file called by javascript that checks the database and pops out your message when the timer has expired.

Comment: should be .load() or .get() or the .ajax() function or jquery