# In Magento how to make a product countdown timer without any extension with the help of JavaScript or PHP or both

Tags: javascript, php, magento, timer, countdown

I am currently working on an eCommerce website on Magento and I need to put a product countdown timer, this timer I want to show it only on those products that are on some kind of limited period offer and I want it to be on the category page and on the single product page. I know this can be easily done with the help of extension's but I am not keen to use any extension. I have searched the web for this solution but was not successful. If this can be done by manual coding using PHP or JavaScript then please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: it might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115620/countdown-timer-built-on-php-and-jquery/16918926#16918926

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible by coding.Just refer below link
http://www.magentoworks.net/magento-create-daily-deal-page-programmatically/

if you want to display timer on category page than you need to put code in list.phtml file also.

Comment: I am sorry but I am getting an error in the timer (NaN days : NaN : NaN) , why is this happening? Its not getting a valid number or something. I have followed the exact code in this link : http://www.magentoworks.net/magento-create-daily-deal-page-programmatically/   Please Help.

Comment: i think you need to change time formate b'coz you dont get proper time for time. Please send me screenshort if possible.

Comment: I need to change the time format where. I am currently doing this on my local server (wampserver) not on my main server. And I have no idea how to upload the screenshot on stackoverflow in the comment section. The special price date set in magento's  backend is from 1/7/2016 to 1/14/2016.

Comment: i think you need to debugged function countdown() {}  this function.

Comment: to get the timer working
Replace:
Countdown(new Date(“”));

to:
Countdown(new Date(“”));

Also add

after
:

Thanks,

Comment: if you use an other language $isGroupDeal == “Yes” have to be change to the correct localisation. For example in Dutch this has to be changed to “Ja”.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">function Countdown(then) {
this.then = then;
function setElement(id, value) {
if (value.length < 2) {
value = "0" + value;
}window.document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = value;
}

Comment: function countdown() {
now  = new Date();
diff = new Date(this.then - now);
seconds_left  = Math.floor(diff.valueOf() / 1000);
seconds  = Math.floor(seconds_left / 1) % 60;
minutes  = Math.floor(seconds_left / 60) % 60;
hours    = Math.floor(seconds_left / 3600) % 24;
days     = Math.floor(seconds_left / 86400) % 86400;

Comment: setElement('countdown-days', days);
setElement('countdown-hours', hours);
setElement('countdown-minutes', minutes);
setElement('countdown-seconds', seconds);
countdown.timer = setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
}function start() {
this.timer = setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
}start(then);
}Countdown(new Date(""));</script>